# Is it possible to lock single elements by index in an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, locking

Suppose I have a program that keeps a list of elements and I want to be able to have a arbitrary number of threads executing jobs and to keep the program threadsafe.

```
class Program() {

    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

    readFromList(int index) {
        synchronized(list.get(index)) {   //If i exclude this lock can other threads access the element 
            Object tmp = list.get(index); //if the lock in writeToList() is active?
            return tmp;
        }
    }

    writeToList(int index, Object obj) {
        synchronized(list.get(index)) {
            list.set(obj);
        }
    }
```

So would it be possible to keep locks per index on the `ArrayList` and when the different threads want to access objects in the list they will only have to wait for locks on specific elements in the array?

Comment: Quick advice: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436946/implement-a-thread-safe-arraylist-in-java-by-locking

Comment: What are you actually trying to ensure by locking the elements? Your `readFromList` element gets the item from the list and then immediately releases the lock; so, the only thing I can imagine you hoping for here is visibility of the element up to the time it was last written with `writeToList`.

Comment: @AndyTurner the lock in 'readFromList' is just to make sure a thread does not read a value while it is being written to.

Comment: @Andrea Yes it is helpful but I'm trying to bypass a global readWritelock by just adding a new lock for each new element in the list.

Comment: `list(i) = obj;` is not valid syntax

Comment: @AndyTurner …and the visibility is not guaranteed with this construct.

Answer (score 4):

`synchronized` does not operate on variables but *objects*. It also doesn’t lock memory, but only provides mutual exclusion and memory visibility guarantees for threads performing `synchronized` *on the same object*.

This implies that any synchronization on a mutable variable doesn’t work at all.

For your specific case, you’d first have to ensure that the `ArrayList` is pre-filled with the necessary number of elements before the multi-threaded access even starts and never changes its size, as otherwise, even the memory visibility of its internal array reference and size fields are not guaranteed.

Then, the general issues with synchronizing on a mutable variable arise.

A code like

```
synchronized(variable) {
    return variable;
}
```

bears two reads of `variable`, the first one being performed *before* entering the `synchronized` block, to determine, which object to synchronize on. Since this first read is performed without any synchronization primitive, it is not guaranteed to see the most recent value. Though, “most recent” doesn’t have much meaning anyway, as the writers performing

```
synchronized(variable) {
    variable = newValue;
}
```

are synchronizing on different objects and hence, have no ordering relation anyway.

But even the most trivial scenario, one writer performing `synchronized(variable) { variable = newValue; }`, followed by one reader performing `synchronized(variable) { return variable; }` does not work, as the writer synchronized *on the old value*, while the reader may read any value in the first access, including *the most recent value*. Since both threads synchronize on different objects, there are no guarantees, which makes the reader’s second read unspecified. As unintuitive as it is, the second read could even read an older value.

But this is not the worst outcome. When you are not using immutable objects like `String` or `Integer`, this racy read may return a more recent object reference, but does not guaranty the visibility of its member fields, ending up in an entirely inconsistent state.

In other words, your issues are not about the mutual exclusion covering only reading and writing a single variable, but the missing memory visibility guarantees.

When you are fine with a fixed size, which your example using only `List.set` and `List.get` implies, you can use an `AtomicReferenceArray`:

```
public class Program {
     // provide needed size
    final AtomicReferenceArray<Object> data = new AtomicReferenceArray<>(100);

    Object readFromList(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }

    // returns old object
    Object writeToList(int index, Object obj) {
        return data.getAndSet(index, obj);
    }
}
```

If you need a changeable size or really need to lock a place for a nontrivial operation, you could use, e.g.

```
public class Program {
    final ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Object> data = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    // returns the new index
    int addToList(Object o) {
        int ix;
        do ix = data.size(); while(data.putIfAbsent(ix, o) != null);
        return ix;
    }

    Object readFromList(int index) {
        return data.get(index);
    }

    void updateList(int index, Object input) {
        data.compute(index, (ix, old) -> {
            // compute based on old and input
            return input;// or computed value
        });
    }
}
```